# Generate custom test result in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm elaborating some **unit tests** and I'm not sure if what I want is possible with **Visual Studio 2008**.

Basically, I'm scanning some classes and for each of them, I want to know if this class is serializable and if it has a default constructor.

I would like to have in the **Test Results** View the list of **ALL** the classes that I had tested and if the test if successful or not.

So, if I'm scanning 325 classes, I want 325 entries in my test results panel.

Is it something possible with Visual Studio 2008, and if it's positive, how I'm gonna do it ?

Thanks, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't figure out my first choice, but I found something very interesting for me.

I simply use the `Console.WriteLine(myStringBuilder.ToString());`

It displays very nicely in the TestResult.

See : [Bill Barnett's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/billbar/)